Insert a new frame in the end of animated WEBP
I have a JPEG image I and a transform function F which has some state S. Every N minutes function's state changes and after that F is applied to my image I. So for the K'th change we have output image I_k which is saved to some directory FRAMES_DIR.
What I want to do is to have an animated WEBP with all generated images so far. Let's call it W_k = WEBP(I_1, ..., I_k). Also it should be done in memory without any saves on disk.
My current approach is using Python and PIL library and looks like that:
webp_frames = []

def get_webp():
    global webp_frames

    nb_frames_processed = len(webp_frames)
    for frame_idx, frame_path in enumerate(sorted(os.listdir(FRAMES_DIR))):
        if frame_idx < nb_frames_processed:
            continue
        frame = Image.open(os.path.join(FRAMES_DIR, frame_path))
        webp_frames.append(frame)

    webp = io.BytesIO()
    webp_frames[0].save(webp, format='WEBP', save_all=True, loop=0, append_images=webp_frames[1:], duration=400)
    return webp

The problem is that after each call of get_webp webp is generated from scratch. It is very slow and has O(K) complexity. I want to find a way to make it in O(1) time by appending a new frame to the end of current WEBP file. Is there any pretty way to do it in Python?

I believe that's possible, though not through Pillow. WEBP is composed of a series of chunks. One of those chunks is a ANMF chunk. I believe that if you copied the ANMF chunk from the new file, removed the XMP and EXIF chunks, appended the ANMF chunk into the old file, then re-added the XMP and EXIF chunks, and fixed the file size field in the fourth through eighth bytes of the file, you would have a new webp file, with a new frame. This would be an O(1) amount of work with respect to the length of the animation.

Thank you for your answer! Yeah, thats the plan I also thought about. Do you know any python libs that can parse webp data?

I investigated Pillow, pywebp, and libwebp. Pillow might be able to do it, but it requires relying on undocumented functionality. See this source file. pywebp doesn't expose the ability to get/set raw chunks, as far as I can tell. libwebp appears to be able to do it, and it has SWIG bindings for Python: https://github.com/webmproject/libwebp/blob/main/swig/README.md#python-swig-bindings You'll want to read the documentation for WebPMuxPushFrame: https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/container-api

Pillow looks like the best choice for me. Will try to reuse its code for my problem. Thank you very much for your help
